# Finding the speed of a standing wave from a graph?

Tags: waves

I am supposed to find the wave speed of a standing wave from a graph of frequency vs linear density, and I'm not exactly sure how. Any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: if you know frequency and wavelength you can calculate speed using this equation $V=f\lambda$ where $v$ is speed, $f$ is frequency and $\lambda$ is wavelength

Comment: By definition a standing wave does not propagate - although it is the superposition of two traveling waves. What exactly do you mean by speed of standing wave? "I am supposed to find" - is this a homework question?

Answer (score 1):

The transverse wave speed in dense medium is $c^2 = \frac{E}{\rho} $ where $E$ is the modulus of elasticity and $\rho$ is mass density. Using linear density $\mu = \rho A$ where $A$ is cross sectional area, the above can be stated as $c^2 \mu = E A$ and if the right hand side is constant (same material and section area) then you can find $c$.